# Ms-Access - invoke stored procedure that returns recordsset

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm struggling with an old and massive system developed on MS-Access 2007, which I'm in charge of its maintenance (including the implementation of changes).

The system interacts with a SQL-Server (2012).

Currently, I need to implement a change in which a new stored procedure needs to be invoked which returns a simple records set, each record being a string.

I tried to use for the invocation some code that already exists within the application (using ADO and copied into the form I'm working on) but nothing I tried works.

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
glblsqlstrToLabels = "EXEC p_Labels_Print 1 , 2878954 , 'OC9991' , '89029' , 4 , 1 , 'dummy'"
```

Though I'm using exactly the same connection string as it is being used all over the application, executing the above statement returns with an error message (something like **...not open...**).

I'm starting to suspect that there is something wrong in the way I'm invoking the function (e.g. not defining any parameters for it and expecting a behavior similar to a `select` statement).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Following are the pieces of code describing what I need to have working:

```
        Dim RS As Recordset 

        ' Connection string is: Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=****;User ID=****;Password=****;Initial Catalog=***;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB.1

        MyCommand = "EXEC p_Labels_Print 1 , 2878954 , 'OC9991' , '89029' , 4 , 1 , 'asdasd'"

        RS.Open MyCommand, CurrentProject.Connection

        Do Until RS.EOF
            Print <record retrieved>
        Loop

        RS.Close
        Set RS = Nothing
```

The error I get is: `Error: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the **full** code that calls the procedure, and the full + exact error message. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested the command in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/185125/how-to-invoke-a-stored-procedure-with-ado-query-using-vba-c-java for example code, implement it, and show us any errors you encounter

Comment: Thank you @Andre. I edited the question with the relevant pieces of code and the error message I get.

Comment: @Kris, the SP was tested within Management Studio and works as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly use ADO and commands, you can't just `rs.Open` a stored procedure.

Use the following Microsoft boilerplate code:

```
   Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
   Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1
   Cmd1.CommandText = "sp_AdoTest"
   Cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   Cmd1.Parameters.Refresh
   Cmd1.Parameters(1).Value = 10
   Set Rs1 = Cmd1.Execute()
```

Where `Conn1` is your ADODB connection, and fill in your parameters and stored procedure name.

Comment: Thank you, Erik. I did as advised, and now i don't get the error. How can i get records from the record set?