# Execute SQL Stored Proc Via Access VBA

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have been attempting to run an executable SQL Stored Procedure from MS Access and am having a little trouble getting Access VBA to run it correctly.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

The data is being gathered from a Form which I believe I have managed to link to the required Dim's but I cannot get the connection to work.

SQL Stored Procedure Execution;

```
EXEC staff.usp_AddNewStaffMember
              @Brand = 'BRAND'
            , @StaffPrefName = 'NAME'
            , @NTLoginID = 'PC LOGIN'
            , @NMCUsername = 'NMC LOGIN'
            , @StaffAuditLevel = 1
            , @EmailAddress = 'EMAIL@Email.com'
            , @PhoneLogin = '0000'
            , @TeamName = 'TEAM NAME'
            , @TeamSegment = 'TEAM SEGMENT'
            , @StartDate = '2017-06-20'
            , @JobTitle = 'JOB TITLE'
```

VBA Code in Access;

```
Function AddStaff()

Dim adoCN               As New ADODB.Connection
Dim sConnString         As String

Dim cmdObjCMD As New ADODB.Command

Dim StaffNameDataTxt
Dim NTloginIDDataTxt
Dim NMCUsernameDataTxt
Dim StaffAuditLevelDataTxt
Dim EmailAddressDataTxt
Dim PhoneLoginDataTxt
Dim TeamNameDataTxt
Dim TeamSegmentDataTxt
Dim StartDateDataTxt
Dim JobTitleDataTxt

DoCmd.OpenForm "AddNewStaff"

Forms!AddNewStaff.TboxStaffName.Value = StaffNameDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxPCLoginID.Value = NTloginIDDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxNMCUsername.Value = NMCUsernameDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxStaffAuditLevel.Value = StaffAuditLevelDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxEmailAddress.Value = EmailAddressDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxPhoneLogin.Value = PhoneLoginDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxTeamName.Value = TeamNameDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxTeamSegment.Value = TeamSegmentDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxStartDate.Value = StartDateDataTxt
Forms!AddNewStaff.TBoxJobTitle.Value = JobTitleDataTxt

Set adoCN = New ADODB.Connection

sConnString = "Provider           =   SQLOLEDB;     " & _
              "Data Source        =   KCOMSQL26;    " & _
              "Initial Catalog    =   EclipseDW;    " & _
              "User ID            =   EclipseDW;    " & _
              "Password           =   ***********;  " & _
              "Trusted_Connection =   Yes;          "

adoCN.Open sConnString

sConnString.QueryDefs("EXEC staff.usp_AddNewStaffMember" & _
                 "  @Brand = 'BRAND'" & _
                 ", @StaffPrefName = StaffNameDataTxt" & _
                 ", @NTLoginID = NTloginIDDataTxt" & _
                 ", @NMCUsername = NMCUsernameDataTxt" & _
                 ", @StaffAuditLevel = StaffAuditLevelDataTxt" & _
                 ", @EmailAddress = EmailAddressDataTxt" & _
                 ", @PhoneLogin = PhoneLoginDataTxt" & _
                 ", @TeamName = TeamNameDataTxt" & _
                 ", @TeamSegment = TeamSegmentDataTxt" & _
                 ", @StartDate = StartDateDataTxt" & _
                 ", @JobTitle = JobTitleDataTxt").Execute

Set sConnString = Nothing
Set cmdObjCMD = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: the values you are using for your connection string are examples. you need to change them to match your database.

Comment: @braX are we bring pranked?

Comment: Yes they are examples and I have kept them as that as the connection actually passes until it get to the Execution Query

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105023. Read the answer there (use `ADODB.Command` instead of a `querydef` since you aren't executing a query)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a duplicate to what is around here for a while.

I will share my approach to this. Once running it can be reused and it is "readable" for a programmer.

Create separate module to store your "links" to the SQL server.

Define Constant (for example):

```
Public Const ODBC_ADO = _
"Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
"Data Source=servername;" & _
"Database=MyDatabase;" & _
"Trusted_Connection=yes;" 'etc. ... '
```

And then I create Public Sub for each SQL Stored procedure:

```
Public Sub SQL_task(*** all your incomming parameters here ***)
        Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim str As String

        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = ODBC_ADO   ' your connection string '
            .CommandTimeout = 10           ' SQL timeout in seconds (by default it is 60, you can turn it down)'
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc ' type of your query to the SQL server'
            .NamedParameters = True  ' set named parameters to true, because it is annoying to send parameters in the right sequence and troubleshoot it...'
            .CommandText = "[staff].[usp_AddNewStaffMember]"   ' name of your stored procedure'            
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Brand", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 1024, "* new Brand *")
            If (Not (IsNull(OptionalVariable))) Or (OptionalVariable<> 0) Then 
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@OptionalVariable", adInteger, adParamInput, , CLng(OptionalVariable))  
                End if
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Response", adBSTR, adParamOutput, 2000)       
            Set rs = .Execute
            .ActiveConnection.Close
            End With
        If Not IsNull(cmd.Parameters("@Response")) Then MsgBox (LTrim(RTrim(CStr(cmd.Parameters("@Response")))))
        Exit Sub
        '--------'
        ErrorExit:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
                    & vbNewLine & "Description: " & Err.description
        'Resume Next

End Sub
```

- @Brand - is exaple of your parameter there,
- @OptionalVariable - dealing with Optional parameters is trick, but this might help you later
- @Response - Output parameter - it is alwas good to know how to get single line Response from SQL server. I use error messages if there is a SQL side verification.

In my SQL Stored prcedure there is something like:

```
SET @Response = N'Something is wrong with your data...'
```

A few links to help you generating the parameters youn need:

- [ADO - Parameters collection.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado)
- [How to Create Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado)